# Remove function doesn't work with multiple instances in multiple loops after serial communication

Tags: c#, c++, while-loop, arduino, serial-communication

I created a simple echoing program to receive data, modify it and then have it echo back the modified and original data. When I run my code, I'm not getting what I'm expecting. I created a windows form to communicate with the Ardino UNO. I'll send the string `("0001","0002","0003","0004"}`.

The data will be read by the Arduino, then runs it to remove any leading 0's, and the returned data should be `{1","2","3","4"}` for the modified and `("0001","0002","0003","0004"}` for the original. When I run my program, the first couple of times I send data I will get weird data echoed back. Sometimes it's shifted or in an order I'm not expecting, but after a couple of runs it echo's back generally what I expected it to.

The only thing is it doesn't fully finish the remove method. Instead what get echoed back is `{"1","0002","0003","0004"}` and `"0001","0002","0003","0004"}`. The second part of the echo is expected, but it seems it only removed leading zeros for the first instance and none of the other times. Since I'm not using a shared index variable in the while loop, and always making it check the first element, I don't think there's anything wrong with my while loop. I know that you can have multiple while loops in a program so I know that can't be an issue.

I don't understand why the remove function only runs in the first loop and none of the others. Am I getting too ahead of myself because it takes about two runs for the expected return data to show? When I don't use a loop and just practice using the remove method on a string, it works fine. Even if the data isn't being echoed back properly, it should still be modified? I should expect to get two different sets of strings regardless if the communication is being slilghtly mis-transmitted.

Arduino Code that reads data, stores it in an array, copies the content of the array into a string to remove leading 0's and then echo's the data back.

```
// Visual Micro is in vMicro>General>Tutorial Mode
// 

// Define Functions below here or use other .ino or cpp files
//
String *rarray = new String[4]; 
String *carray = new String[4]; 
int blinks;

// The setup() function runs once each time the micro-controller starts
void setup()
{
pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Arduino is Ready");

}

// Add the main program code into the continuous loop() function
void loop()
{
    getstring();
    StringtoInt0();
    StringtoInt1();
    StringtoInt2();
    StringtoInt3();
    blink();
    echo();
    delay(1000);
}

void getstring()
{
    int ndx = 0;
    String rs;
    while (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        rs = Serial.readStringUntil('\0');
        rarray[ndx] = rs;
        carray[ndx] = rarray[ndx];
        ndx++;
        if (ndx >= 4)
            break;
    }
}
void StringtoInt0()
{
    String R0B0 = carray[0];//get string from element 0
    while (R0B0[0] == '0')//while first char is 0
    {
        R0B0.remove(0, 1);//remove it
    }
    Serial.println(R0B0);//return the modified data back to the GUI
    int int0 = R0B0.toInt();//convert a string into an integer
    delay(10);//allow time for the data to be transmitted.
    //--------------------------------
}
void StringtoInt1()
{
    String R0B = carray[1];
    while (R0B[0] == '0')
    {
        R0B.remove(0, 1);
    }
    Serial.println(R0B);
    blinks = R0B.toInt();

            delay(10);
    //--------------------------------
}
void StringtoInt2()
{
    String R0B2 = carray[2];
    while (R0B2[0] == '0')

    {
        R0B2.remove(0, 1);
    }
    Serial.println(R0B2);
    int int2 = R0B2.toInt();

    delay(10);
    //--------------------------------
}
void StringtoInt3()
{
    String R0B3 = carray[3];
    while (R0B3[0] == '0')
        {
            R0B3.remove(0, 1);
        }
    Serial.println(R0B3);
    int int3 = R0B3.toInt();

    delay(10);
}
//--------------------------------

void blink()
{
    for (int b = 1; b <= blinks; b++)
    {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        delay(250);
    }
}
void echo()
{
    for (int rs = 0; rs <= 3; rs++)
    {
        Serial.println(carray[rs]);//return the original sent data
        delay(20);
    }

}
```

Windows Form that transmits data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;
namespace Blink_with_String_GUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string S0; string S1; string S2; string S3;
        int S0I; int S1I; int S2I; int S3I;
        S0I = Convert.ToInt16(b0.Value);
        S1I = Convert.ToInt16(b1.Value);
        S2I = Convert.ToInt16(b2.Value);
        S3I = Convert.ToInt16(b3.Value);
        S0 = S0I.ToString("D4");
        S1 = S1I.ToString("D4");
        S2 = S2I.ToString("D4");
        S3 = S3I.ToString("D4");
        label1.Text = S0;
        label2.Text = S1;
        label3.Text = S2;
        label4.Text = S3;

        string[] string1 = new string[] { S0, S1, S2, S3 };

        //-----
        port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        port.Open();
        for (int s = 0; s <= 3; s++)    //Write string of padded int
        {
            port.WriteLine(string1[s]);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        string rs1; string rs2; string rs3; string rs4; string rs5; string rs6; string rs7; string rs8; string rs9;
        rs1 = port.ReadLine();
        rs2 = port.ReadLine();
        rs3 = port.ReadLine();
        rs4 = port.ReadLine();
        rs5 = port.ReadLine();
        rs6 = port.ReadLine();
        rs7 = port.ReadLine();
        rs8 = port.ReadLine();
        rs9 = port.ReadLine();


        label8.Text = rs1;
        label7.Text = rs2;
        label6.Text = rs3;
        label5.Text = rs4;

        label12.Text = rs5;
        label11.Text = rs6;
        label10.Text = rs7;
        label9.Text = rs8;





        port.Close();
```

Comment: Are you sure about the [tag:c#] tag?

Comment: You are trying to read 4 nul terminated strings, but you never send any nul characters.

Comment: C# was automatically recommended. The windows form runs on C#.

Comment: @gre_gor But strings are null terminated character arrays,  so isn't it reading up to the nul termination character of the string?

Comment: nul terminators aren't sent.

Comment: @gre_gor I see, Thanks. When I changed it to read for new line terminated instead of nul termination the remove method worked fine for the 3 elements, but now the first element messed up.

Answer (score 0):

The Null Character within the string array does not get written. Therefore you can't try to read for said character. Instead waiting to read `'\n'` works since writeLine prints a new line character. Thanks Gre_Gor